# Converting structure to array

Tags: matlab

Here is a simplified version of a
consider the data structure below in Matlab:

```
 struct(1).left=1;struct(2).left=2;struct(3).left=3;
```

Now I would like to copy that into an array of integer

```
K>> arrayL(1:3)=struct.left
```

arrayL =

```
 1     1     1
```

why it only copeis the first elements of struct.left into arrayL? how can I copy the entire struct(1:3) into arrayL  so that it contains 1,2,3?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have matlab handy at the moment, but try `arrayL = [struct.left];` (because `struct.left` by itself returns 3 separate answers, one for each element in `struct`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use cell2mat function http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html